# How to remove certain elements from my array in my Java code

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on the following coding prompt for my class:
Your    task    is  to  write   a   method  with    the following   signature:

```
public static String[] removeFromArray(String[] arr, String toRemove)
```

The method  should  return  a   string  array   that    has the same    contents    as  arr,    except  without any 
occurrences of  the toRemove    string. For example,    if  your    method  is  called  by  the code    below

```
String[] test = {“this”, “is”, “the”, “example”, “of”, “the”, “call”};
String[] result = removeFromArray(test, “the”);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

it  should  generate    the following   output:

```
[this, is, example, of, call]
```

Note:   Your    method  will    be  passed  values  for arr and toRemove    by  the testing program – you   should  not 
read    these   values  in  from    the user    inside  your    method. Also,   you must    write   this    method  with    the 
signature   requested   above   in  order   to  receive credit. You do  not need    to  write   the code    that    calls   the 
method  – only  the method  itself.
Hint:   Because you must    specify the length  of  an  array   when    you create  it, you will    likely  need    to  make
two loops   through the input   array:  one to  count   the number  of  occurrences of  the toRemove    string  so
that    you can create  the new array   with    the proper  size    and a   second  to  copy    all of  the other   strings to  the new array.

I have everything working in my code but the last part where I have to print out the new array does not work, I know I have make it smaller so it will print out properly, but I can't get that part to work. I know I have to get rid of the null, but I don't know how. Also my code has to work for any array not just the test case I have. Some help or advice would really be nice. Thank you very much!!! :)
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] test = {"this", "is", "the", "example", "of", "the", "call"};
    String[] remove = removeFromArray(test, "the");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(remove));
}

public static String[] removeFromArray(String[] arr, String toRemove) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].equals(toRemove)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    String[] result = new String[arr.length - count];
    //for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //  if(!arr[i].equals(toRemove)){
    //    result[].equals(arr[i]);
    //}

    //}
    return result;
}
```

Comment: ***..." does not work,"*** what does this mean? is exploiding? is printing something else?

Comment: [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, for the answer of the title itself, it is `System.arraycopy`. But the content is not related to the title.

Comment: @Alex Yes, because the OP is *"a beginner programmer"* so they may not be aware of the API, so, it's now been highlighted :)

Comment: You could consider using streams. `Arrays.stream(arr).filter(v -> !v.equals(toRemove)).toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you approach looks ok, it looks like the commented code yor are trying to assign the new array with the wrong emthod

you should use  `result[i] =  arr[i] ;` instead of `result[].equals(arr[i]);`

do at the end:

```
String[] result = new String[arr.length - count];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(!toRemove.equals(arr[i])){
       result[k] =  arr[i];
       k++;
    }

}
return result;
```

Comment: Sir, I think, !toRemove.equals(arr[i]) is a better alternative to !arr[i].equals(toRemove).

Answer (score 0):

Your last part should be assigning the value to the array one by one.

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(!toRemove.equals(arr[i])){
        result[j++] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's asking you to return a new String array which excludes the given word. Loop through the array and add word which does not equal to the given word.

```
public static String[] removeFromArray(String[] arr, String toRemove){
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s : arr)
        if(!s.equals(toRemove))
            words.add(s);
    return words.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Since array size cannot be changed after being created, use an ArrayList to store the words, then return as an array.

Comment: Thank you all so much!!! I really appreciate the help!! I knew it had to be something simple. Thank you so much!! Have a wonderful night!

Answer (score 0):

I know you're new to programming itself, so the solutions given are perfectly fine.

However, using Java, you'd usually use the libraries; in this case, the Collections library. If you're using Java 8, this is how you would do it:

```
public static String[] removeFromArray(String[] arr, String toRemove) {
    // create a List and fill it with your items
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
    Collections.addAll(list, arr);

    // remove the items that are equal to the one to be removed
    list.removeIf(s -> toRemove.equals(s));

    // transfer back to array
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

Then, there are Java 8 Streams, which would make this

```
public static String[] removeFromArray(String[] arr, String toRemove) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)             // create stream from array
        .filter(s -> !toRemove.equals(s)) // filter out items
        .toArray(String[]::new);          // create array from stream
}
```